# Use 0 or BIND_AUTO_CREATE for bindService's flag

Tags: android

By referring to [bindService (Intent service, ServiceConnection conn, int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService%28android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int%29)

May I know, when should we use 0 for `flags`, and when should we should we use `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` for `flags`? The documentation doesn't explain what is the meaning of 0 for flags.

### Example for using 0 as `flags`

```
// Start auto complete service.
autoCompleteServiceIntent = new Intent(AutoCompleteService.class.getName()); 
startService(autoCompleteServiceIntent);
bindService(autoCompleteServiceIntent, serviceConnection, 0);
```

### Example for using `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` as `flags`

```
mContext.bindService(new Intent("com.android.vending.billing.InAppBillingService.BIND"),
                             mServiceConn, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

For method `bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, flag)` if `flag = Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE` is used it will bind the `service` and start the service,
 but if `"0"` is used, method will return true and will not start service until a call like `startService(Intent)` is made to start the `service`.
 One of the common use of `"0"` is in the case where an activity to connect to a local service if that service is running, otherwise you can start the service.

Comment: Are you sure about the part where you say 
_but if "0" is used, method will return true and will not start service_?  
The documentation states 
_Returns: If you have successfully bound to the service, true is returned; false is returned if the connection is not made so you will not receive the service object._

Comment: Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE does not start the service, it only creates it.

Comment: What happens when you pass `0` and the service is not already started? What does `bindService` return?

Answer (score 13):

Semantically, use `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` if you're binding to a service whose lifetime is only valid for as long as it has clients bound to it. That's because the minute all clients have unbound from it, it will go down.

Do not use `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` - or perhaps I should rephrase: there's no point in using `BIND_AUTO_CREATE`, if you're really just temporarily binding to a service in order to query or control it, and it is reasonable that this service would live on after you're done. For those cases, binding is for establishing a connection, and the service' lifecycle should be managed using `startService()` and `stopService()` (or `stopSelf()` in some cases).

A commonly mentioned example of the latter case is clearly described by Google in the docs on [bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html):

> "... For example, a music player might find it useful to allow its service to run indefinitely and also provide binding. This way, an activity can start the service to play some music and the music continues to play even if the user leaves the application. Then, when the user returns to the application, the activity can bind to the service to regain control of playback."

Overall, I would say that the usage of the flag really distinguishes two very different types of use cases, rather than fine-tuned versions of the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `startService()`, then bind to a Service using `bindService()` with `BIND_AUTO_CREATE` and then call `stopService()`, in this case Service will not be stopped until all bound clients are unbound.

In the same situation, if you call `bindService()` with `0` the Service will be stopped and its `onUnbind()` and `onDestroy()` callback called.