# bindService() in client app fails when trying to do IPC with another app

Tags: android, aidl

I wanted to get some experience with android IPC using AIDL. I wanted to see if it was possible to communicate between two distinct android apps.

My problem is that invoking `bindService` in the second app, to communicate with the first app's `FactorialService`, service always fails. My first app activity `MainActivity` which tries to call `bindService` always log the fact that `bindService` returns `false`. Plus `MainActivity` (which implements `ServiceConnection`) of this second app (the client app)    never gets its callback method `onServiceConnected` called.

So, in a **first application** which runs a service called `FactorialService`

- I defined an
  interface, `IFactorialService.aidl`:

  ```
  package com.simonlbc.factorialcommon;

  import com.simonlbc.factorialcommon.FactorialRequest;
  import com.simonlbc.factorialcommon.FactorialResponse;

  interface IFactorialService {
      FactorialResponse fact(in FactorialRequest r);
  }
  ```

`FactorialRequest` contains an input number (say n). `fact` returns `n!` along with other information.

- In the same application I created a class `IFactorialServiceImplem`
  implementing that aidl interface.

  ```
  package com.example.simonlbc.factorialservice;
  import android.app.Service;
  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.IBinder;
  import android.os.SystemClock;
  import com.simonlbc.factorialcommon.FactorialResponse;
  import com.simonlbc.factorialcommon.FactorialRequest;

  public class IFactorialServiceImplem extends com.simonlbc.factorialcommon.IFactorialService.Stub {

      public long recursiveFact(int n) {
          if (n < 0)
              throw new IllegalArgumentException("input fa");
          if (n == 1 || n == 0)
              return 1;
          else {
              return n * recursiveFact(n-1);
          }
      }

      public long iterativeFact(int n) {
          long res = 1;
          for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
              res *= i;
          return res;
      }
      public FactorialResponse fact(FactorialRequest r) {
          long timeInMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
          long result = 0;

          switch(r.getChoice()) {
              case RECURSIVE:
                  result = recursiveFact(r.getInNb());
                  break;
              case ITERATIVE:
                  result = iterativeFact(r.getInNb());
          }
          timeInMillis = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - timeInMillis;

          return new FactorialResponse(result, timeInMillis);
      }
  }
  ```

  - I then created a `Service` that would be used to communicate a `IFactorialService` instance  to possible clients:

    ```
    package com.example.simonlbc.factorialservice;
    import android.app.Service;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.IBinder;
    import android.util.Log;
    import com.simonlbc.factorialcommon.IFactorialService;

    public class FactorialService extends Service {

        private IFactorialServiceImplem s = null;
        private static final String TAG = "FactorialService";

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();
            s = new IFactorialServiceImplem();
            Log.d(TAG, "onCreate'd");
        }
            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onBind()'d");
                return this.s;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onUnbind()'d");
                return super.onUnbind(intent);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy()'d");
                s = null;
                super.onDestroy();
            }
        }
    ```

    - the manifest of this first "service" app is the following:

    ```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <service
            android:name=".FactorialService">
            <!--
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            android:process=":remote"
            -->

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.simonlbc.factorialservice.FactorialService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
    ```
  - the first app contains a Launcher activity which simply starts the service as so:

    ```
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_service);
            curPackage = getString(R.string.packageService);
            MainActivity.this.startService(
                    new Intent()
                            .setAction(curPackage + ".FactorialService")
                            .setPackage(curPackage)
            );
        }
    ```

---

---

- My **second app**'s launcher activity is such as:

  `public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, ServiceConnection`

  I want `MainActivity` of this second app to
  communicate with the first's app `IFactorialService`.  In onResume I 
  try to bind with the first app's service:

  ```
     @Override
     protected void onResume() {
         super.onResume();
         Intent i = new Intent();
         i.setAction("com.example.simonlbc.factorialservice.FactorialService");
         i.setPackage("com.example.simonlbc");
         if (!super.bindService(i, this, BIND_AUTO_CREATE))
             Log.w(TAG, "Failed to bind our service!!!");
     }
  ```

But it seems `bindService` fails. Indeed everytime I pause the app and return to it, or start it. "Failed to bind our service!!!" is displayed.

Note that the two app share an Android Library module containing the definitions of the needed aidl files.

Do you see anything that would allow `bindService()` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `super.bindservice()` ? Instead, can you try this `getApplicationContext().bindservice()`

Also, if this does not work either, try the following modification of your code:

```
   Intent i = new Intent("com.example.simonlbc.factorialservice.FactorialService");
   if(getApplicationContext().startService(i) != null){
       if (!getApplicationContext().bindService(i, serviceConnection, 0))
           Log.w(TAG, "Failed to bind our service!!!");
   }
```

where `seriveConnection` is an object of service connection (I prefer not to use `this` for `ServiceConnection` ). Also, your service should have the proper `Action` set, otherwise it won't start

Comment: Thanks, putting `this` or `getApplicationContext` helped. I still needed the i.setPackage("com.example.simonlbc.factorialService") otherwise I would get this RuntimeError: `Service Intent must be explicit`. On that point I had also made a typo! Instead of `com.example.simonlbc.factorialService` I had written `com.example.simonlbc` in `i.setPackage`. This would point to the parent package of the service in the first app instead of the exact package of the service in the first app.

Comment: Also it seems that adding `if(getApplicationContext().startService(i) != null){` is only necessary I don't have the two apps running at the same time. But it is really nice to see that if I don't run the "Service" app the "Client" app seems to be able to run the service! And if the two apps are running at the same time the client app is able to communicate with the already running service in the "Service" app.

Comment: Another note for myself or other possibly other people. I had hesitated on putting the following tags in the Service app manifest next to <service>:        
` android:enabled="true"
 android:exported="true"
 android:process=":remote"`
`exported` is already defaulted to true which makes the service usable from outside the app. `android:process=":remote"` from the [doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html) is useless for me (I thought it was saying that the service was usable outside of the app, it's not the case). `enabled` is true by default.

Comment: Also Ankur Aggarwal what is the 0 flag for in `bindService`?

Comment: @Simonlbc Explanation for `0` here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746245/use-0-or-bind-auto-create-for-bindservices-flag